# How to wait for widget initialization

Tags: jquery

I have two widgets: main and child. Main widget initializes child widget in a loop. Child widgets are attached to some input field elements:

Despite I have the same 'child' widget for two other elements, they have common logic, and they have to exchange some data. There is getCurrentValue() function which they call when they need get some information from their pair-element.

Another words I do this:

In some place of widget I call:

```
let dataFromFirstWidget = $element1.child("getCurrentValue");
```

And in another place I call:

```
let dataFromSecondWidget = $element2.child("getCurrentValue");
```

Unfortunatelly I have to get information from second widget before it is initialized. And therefore I always get 'Error: cannot call methods on spinner prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'getCurrentValue'.'

How can I wait for initialization of second widget in my context (I mean in situation when one widget calls another in a loop)? How can I do this?

```
(function ($) {

$.widget("mainWidget", {
    options: {
    // some options
    },
    
    _create: function () {
        
        for (var r = 0; r < 5; r++) {
            let $element = $xrow.find("nameOfElement']").eq(0);
            $element.relatedWidget();
            let $element2 = $xrow.find("nameOfElement']").eq(1);
            $element2.relatedWidget();
        }
    }
}
})(jQuery);

(function ($) {

$.widget("relatedWidget", {
    getCurrentValue: function () {
        return this.val();
    },
}
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: sounds like you are looking for jquery deferred; https://learn.jquery.com/code-organization/deferreds/examples/

Comment: The first widget could add a data attribute to the body and the second could wait for that to be added before it starts with the work...

Comment: @Steve0 unfortunatelly I didnt understand how I can use it. Can you give me simple example? It doesnt metter would it works or not, I just need some example and short explanation.